# How do I disable ViewController dismissal on left-to-right swipe?

Tags: ios, ipad, transition, segue, viewcontroller

Does anyone know how to prevent a view controller from being dismissed (or popped from the NavigationController stack) as a result of swiping from left to right from the extreme left of the screen?

I've uploaded a video to help explain what I mean. This behaviour occurs in both the simulator and physical device.

http://youtu.be/fyNEDT140TQ

Reason: Someone will be signing the screen and as such, starting from the left of the screen will cause the navigationcontroller to pop the current view controller (ie. go back a screen).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use the below code. It is not supported in IOS 6. So you have to check it first

```
if ([self.navigationController respondsToSelector:@selector(interactivePopGestureRecognizer)] && [self checkOSVersion] >= 7) {
    self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
}

- (int)checkOSVersion {

    NSArray *ver = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
    int osVerson = [[ver objectAtIndex:0] intValue];
    return osVerson;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The gesture is working by the UINavigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer. You can disable this behaviour by set interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enable to NO

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3+**

```
self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = false
```

you'll want to unwrap it if you don't know if the view will have a navigation controller.

```
if self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled != nil {
    self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = false
    }
```